# Is there an easy formula to pick up date from one tab to another based on the month

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create an analysis tab for our yearly management accounts. I want to be able to show the data for a specific cost (ie marketing) based on the month we are reporting on.

For example if I put April 20 in a cell on the analysis tab, I want the marketing row to pick up the actual costs in from the P&L tab for April 20. Then when we are looking at May 20 I want the data in the marketing cell to change to May actual costs.

Any ideas? Ive tried vlookup, indirect, Hlookups but coming back with errors.

Comment: Post the formulas you've tried and perhaps a screenshot of your data.

Comment: Requesting to update the question. It should be pickup Data (not date). The answer will depend upon how the P&L tab data is arranged. Please add a screen shot of that sheet. Also, note that if you are entering Month in "Date" format on analysis tab and there are columns for Months in P&L Tab formatted as text, the formula will change accordingly.